# Can I travel back to US

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens

I have an H-1B visa stamped till Sep-2017 and have stamped Schengen  Visa  and I am supposed to travel to Germany for 2 weeks and just noticed my passport will expire in Jun 2017 which is 5 months 15 days when I return from Germany to US. Can I travel to Germany with the current passport. Renew the passport when I am back to US.

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: Nationality-Indian

Answer (score 3):

Given the information that you are on an Indian passport, India is on the [list of countries](https://fam.state.gov/FAM/09FAM/09FAM040309.html#M403_9_3_B_2) who have agreements with the US to accept their passports for return of their nationals up to 6 months after expiry, so you can enter the US up to your passport's expiration. However, note that you will only be admitted until the passport's expiration, which will be only a few months. After you renew your passport, you will need to either have your employer file I-129 to extend your status, or you need to leave and re-enter the US to be admitted until your H1b petition's expiration.

Answer (score 2):

> Can i Travel to Germany with the current passport.

Yes, the Schengen passport validity requirements are:

> [Passport/Visa requirements](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-nationals/index_en.htm)
>
> If you are a non-EU national wishing to visit or travel within the EU,
>   you will need a passport:
>
> - valid for at least 3 months after the date you intend to leave the EU country you are visiting,
> - which was issued within the previous 10 years,

Comment: Might it not be a problem for the OP to _return_ to USA as a nonimmigrant (H-1B is considered a nonimmigrant status) with a passport that is valid for less than 6 months?

Comment: I don't see any issues in going to Germany,but i doubt whether there will be an issue in USA while return at board of entry.But still i have Valid Visa till Sep-2017

Comment: I have to renew my passport only after returning from Germany , now I don't have time to renew herr and no option to renew in Germany